# ZeroMQ C++ client is not receiving

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, zeromq

I have recently started a new project with the [Pupil](https://pupil-labs.com/) eyetracker. To broadcast the tracking information to additional clients they use [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/). I have verified that their server is correctly running by trying their simple Python client example:

```
import zmq
import json

#network setup
port = "5000"
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:"+port)

# recv all messages
socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, '')

while True:
    topic =  socket.recv_multipart()
    #msg = json.loads(topic)
    print  "\n\n",topic[0] #,":\n",msg
```

Since my project should be a C++ I have tried translating it in C++ using ZeroMQ examples like this:

```
#include "zmq.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    //  Prepare our context and socket
    zmq::context_t context(1);
    zmq::socket_t socket(context, ZMQ_SUB);

    std::cout << "Connecting to hello world server" << std::endl;
    socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5000");

    socket.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "");

    //  Do 100 requests, waiting each time for a response
    for (int request_nbr = 0; request_nbr != 100; request_nbr++) {

        //  Get the message.
        zmq::message_t msg;
        socket.recv(&msg);
        std::cout << "Received World " << msg.data() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately this does not work, the C++ client just hangs at socket.recv(&msg); waiting for a message it never receives.

For the project I am using Visual Studio 2013 and the ZeroMQ library libzmq-v120-mt-4_0_4.lib which came with the ZeroMQ installation (I did not compile it). To set it up I used [this](https://gerrydevstory.com/2015/04/24/setting-up-zeromq-c-on-visual-studio/) tutorial, not pasting it whole because I find it a bit irrelevant.

The configuration I use is x64 whereas Pupil's is 32bit, I think, but this should be irrelevant for ZeroMQ if I am not mistaken.

Pupil uses pyzmq which should be compatible with 4.04 zmq lib.

Comment: You may want to check if Pupil's pyzmq _really_ uses zmq 4.0.4. Personally I have had compatibility problems between different versions before (even crashes), so I suggest you verify the actual versions used.

Comment: Pupil recommends  pyzmq‑14.7.0 which should be supporting 4.1.x zmq. This is the information I could find. I can see their libzmq.pyd file but I don't think I can check the version. For what is worth, the running Python client actually uses the latest pyzmq, pyzmq-15.2.0-cp27

Comment: You can check the versions like [this](http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:version)

Comment: Thank you. The ZMQ version I have installed for Python is 4.1.2. I have managed to download and compile the latest Libzmq master branch but this did not solve my problem.

Comment: Hm. If you have the same problem running definitely identical zmq versions on both ends, then I'm not sure what's going on. Personally I would start experimenting a little, by trying different ports, checking `netstat`, trying to connect manually via telnet/PuTTY, etc. to get more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, still unknown to me, the wrapper zmq.hpp is not working in my case. Using a solution from the [book](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/zeromq/9781449334437/ch01s07.html) which does not use this helper solcer the issue for me

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    void *context = zmq_ctx_new();

    //  Socket to talk to server
    void *subscriber = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_SUB);
    int rc = zmq_connect(subscriber, "tcp://127.0.0.1:5000");
    assert(rc == 0);

    rc = zmq_setsockopt(subscriber, ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "", strlen(""));
    assert(rc == 0);

    //  Process 100 updates
    int update_nbr;
    long total_temp = 0;
    for (update_nbr = 0; update_nbr < 100; update_nbr++) {
        char msg[256];
        rc = zmq_recv(subscriber, msg, 256, 0);
        std::cout << "Received World " << msg << std::endl;
    }

    zmq_close(subscriber);
    zmq_ctx_destroy(context);
    return 0;
}
```